# If statement works but else if doesn't. why?

Tags: java

I am having trouble with getting my program to run properly. I was able to clear any syntax errors, but now I am having issued with my output.
I have the following statement and the ELSE IF doesn't seem to be working? it always ignores the else if codes. i can't understand the problem with the code. 
Can anybody help me?

```
private void login_btnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 

    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement stmt;
    ResultSet rs;

    try {       

         //connect to the database
        String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1537/LoginSystem";
        String uName = "root";
        String uPass = "root";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);

        String user = username_txt.getText();
        String pass = passwordField_txt.getText();

        String sql = "Select USERNAME,PASSWORD from LOGINSYSTEM where USERNAME = '"+user+"' AND PASSWORD = '"+pass+"'";
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);        

        rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()) {

            String s1 = rs.getString(1);
            String s2 = rs.getString(2);

            if(user.equals(s1) && pass.equals(s2)) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Successfull!");
                Account obj = new Account();
                obj.setVisible(true);

            } else if(!user.equals(s1) && !pass.equals(s2)) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Failed!");

            } else if(!pass.equals(s2)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter A Valid Password.");
                passwordField_txt.setText(null);
            }
        }

    } catch(SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: what output are you getting?

Comment: your sql query will always return ONLY rows with valid login and password, so its impossible to enter else if statement

Comment: what if my username is `'); DROP TABLE LOGINSYSTEM;--`?

Comment: Why are you storing passwords?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query returns matching `user` and `pass` values so there is no condition where `!user.equals(s1) && !pass.equals(s2)` is satisified. Always use `PreparedStatement` placeholders rather than `String` concatenation to protect against SQL Injection.

Differentiating the error between an invalid usernames and passwords allows any would-be hacker an insight what information can be used to gain access to the system.

If anything the code should look like

```
if (rs.next()) {

   String s1 = rs.getString(1);
   String s2 = rs.getString(2);

   // user and pass already match from SQL - no if logic necessary

} else {
     // display GENERIC login failure message
}
```

But storing passwords in a database is a *major* security flaw so this whole approach is **not safe**. The typical approach is to store the password using a [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) to guard against the use of [rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table). To verify the password the same hashing algorithm and salt can be used to compare against what is stored in the database,

Comment: i want else if statements to be executed when the username and password doesn't matches. what to do then?

Comment: From the query it appears that you are only getting values that match. Debug your code yourself to verify that this is so. In that case the `else if` block is never entered

Comment: can you please provide code for what i want to do? i'm stuck!

Comment: thank you for the help but this only checks the first row of the database rather than checking all rows of the database where the username and password matches.

Answer (score 0):

First this is subject to a SQL injection attack.  Learn about prepared statements, and use the parameter passing feature of prepared statements, to prevent user names like: [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Second, your where statement will **only** return back rows where the user name and password are exact matches to the inputted values.  Therefore, comparing a non-null result will be **guaranteed** to always match, barring some incredibly bizarre database bug.

If you ask me to give you a fruit where the fruit is a red apple, then assuming that I am trusted, when I give you a red apple, checking to see if the apple is not an apple, or that red is not red will result in checking a condition that is never met.

Comment: thank you! but can you please provide proper code for what i want to do?

Comment: I am happy to help you learn for free; but if you want me to provide the solution for you, I have reasonable contracting rates.  read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html  http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/05/best-practices-while-dealing-with.html http://www.jasypt.org/howtoencryptuserpasswords.html

Answer (score 0):

If usernames are forced unique, you can take that matching condition for the password out of the query. Then just query for the username matching condition and get the username and password for that row. This way you can check for incorrect password OR incorrect username more easily.  The way it is now the query will only return results when the username and password are correct and you will never enter your else if's.